# tomcat context resource not working

Tags: centos, tomcat6, centos6

i have a tomcat6 server running on a CentOS 6 machine and so far so good.
in one of my webapps i need to use a context param to access an external folder located in the filesystem, i configured my server.xml like this (relevant portion of `<Host>` tag only) :

```
<Context path="/userimages" docBase="/home/someuser/faces/32x32" debug="0" reloadable="true" crossContext="true"/>
```

when i start the server i get this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base /home/someuser/faces/32x32 does not exist or is not a readable directory
```

i read something about folder permission so i set both "32x32" and "webapps" folder to 777, but it's still not working...any idea of how to fix this ?

P.S. on windows OS it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to put your data into **/usr/share/tomcat6/conf/context.xml** which is a symlink to **/etc/tomcat6/context.xml** on CentOS 6. At least tomcat6 does read the contents of that file when it restarts, and I had some luck getting resource data loaded from there.  It would seem that this file is new in tomcat6.

I used strace to check which files it was visiting and it does run stat() on the various files like **/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/*/META-INF/context.xml** but nowhere does it actually open() those files, so I'm pretty sure it does not read the contents. Maybe some bug? Maybe imaginary future feature?

I managed to get Plandora (uses context to supply MySQL database connection details) running on CentOS 6 with these packages (from yum):

```
apache-tomcat-apis-0.1-1.el6.noarch
java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-1.61.1.11.11.el6_4.i686
mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-6.el6.noarch
tomcat6-6.0.24-52.el6_4.noarch
tomcat6-servlet-2.5-api-6.0.24-52.el6_4.noarch
tomcat6-el-2.1-api-6.0.24-52.el6_4.noarch
tomcat6-admin-webapps-6.0.24-52.el6_4.noarch
tomcat6-jsp-2.1-api-6.0.24-52.el6_4.noarch
tomcat6-lib-6.0.24-52.el6_4.noarch
tomcat6-webapps-6.0.24-52.el6_4.noarch
```

Just in case anyone else is trying to get Plandora to work on CentOS 6, you also need to make sure you symlink:

```
 ln -s /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar /usr/share/tomcat6/lib/
```